# Error while creating query as a Missing operator?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I am trying to extract data in a tabular format with different values for part-time and full-time, to get an output like this:

[image: Expected Output]

but my query generates this error:

> syntax error missing operator

What operator is missing from this query?

```
SELECT
    BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_TERM_DESC,
    Count(BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_FULL_PART_IND="F") AS ["Full-time Undergraduate Enrollment"], 
    Count(IIf(BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_FULL_PART_IND="P",1,Null)) AS ["Part-time Undergraduate Enrollment"]
FROM BANINST1_SZVIRST
GROUP BY 
    BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_TERM_DESC, 
    BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_TERM_CODE, 
    BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_LEVL_CODE, 
    BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_FULL_PART_IND
HAVING
    (((BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_TERM_CODE) In ("201020","201120","201220","201320","201420","201520","201620"))
    AND ((BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_LEVL_CODE)="01"));
```

Comment: Not executing? Syntax error? Run-time error? No result? etc.

Comment: Its showing me "syntax Error" from the 6th line of the given code.

Comment: Why are you field names enclosed in both square brackets AND double quotes? (I think they are double quotes, but your code is a picture and your screen capture tool is a potato).

Comment: If you remove that line (temporarily), does it execute?

Comment: Your `Count()` functions look like: `COUNT(IIF() AND (<some expression>))` which seems wrong. Like that would evaluate to `COUNT(true AND true)` which would be `count(true)`, which might work, but is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: SZVIRST_LEVL_CODE="01" , for gradutae students

Comment: SZVIRST_LEVL_CODE="02" , for undergraduate students

Comment: The count(iif()) function for the `SZVIRIT_LEVL_CODE` appears to be missing a close bracket. Or have I misread that line?

Comment: Don't vandalize your questions. They are here for people after you, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have 4 different conditions happening here that you are testing for:

1. Counts of people that are Full-Time
2. Counts of people that are Part-Time
3. Counts of people that are Graduate
4. Counts of people that are UnderGraduate

You are on the right track to use the `iif()` statement. I think that was from a previous question you asked a day or two ago. The `iif()` statements would be:

```
SUM(IIF(BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_FULL_PART_IND="F", 1, 0)) as [FullTime],
SUM(IIF(BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_FULL_PART_IND="P", 1, 0)) as [PartTime],
SUM(IIF(SZVIRST_LEVL_CODE="01", 1, 0)) as [Graduate],
SUM(IIF(SZVIRST_LEVL_CODE="02", 1, 0)) as [UnderGraduate],
```

I changed the `COUNT()` to a `SUM()` just because it feels more natural since the `IIF()` is returning a 1 or a 0. You could change that back to a `COUNT(Iif(<condition>, 1, null))` and it would fine too.

### Checking for two conditions

If you want to combine a couple of conditions to get a count, the formula changes slightly.

For insstance, if you wanted a count of all Full-Time People that are also Under Graduates you could use:

```
SUM(IIF(BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_FULL_PART_IND="F" AND SZVIRST_LEVL_CODE="02", 1, 0)) AS [FullTimeUnderGraduates]
```

Here we put BOTH conditions INSIDE the first parameters of the `IIF()` formula. If both are `TRUE`, it returns a `1`, then all those `1`s gets summed up.

Lastly, if you are wanting to `count`/`sum` both `Graduate` and `Under Graduates` in your query, then you can't exclude them in your `HAVING` clause. So you'll need to remove the bit that reads:

```
((BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_LEVL_CODE)="01")
```

Otherwise a test like

```
iif(BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_LEVL_CODE="01", 1, 0)
```

will ALWAYS return a `1` and

```
iif(BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_LEVL_CODE="02", 1, 0)
```

will ALWAYS return `0`

### Example

The following should run in your database and give you a good working example of the logic discussed above:

```
SELECT
    BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_TERM_DESC,
    SUM(IIF(BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_FULL_PART_IND="F", 1, 0)) as [FullTime],
    SUM(IIF(BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_FULL_PART_IND="P", 1, 0)) as [PartTime],
    SUM(IIF(SZVIRST_LEVL_CODE="01", 1, 0)) as [Graduate],
    SUM(IIF(SZVIRST_LEVL_CODE="02", 1, 0)) as [UnderGraduate],
    SUM(IIF(BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_FULL_PART_IND="F" AND SZVIRST_LEVL_CODE="02", 1, 0)) AS [FullTimeUnderGraduates],
    SUM(IIF(BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_FULL_PART_IND="P" AND SZVIRST_LEVL_CODE="02", 1, 0)) AS [PartTimeUnderGraduates],
    SUM(IIF(BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_FULL_PART_IND="F" AND SZVIRST_LEVL_CODE="01", 1, 0)) AS [FullTimeGraduates],
    SUM(IIF(BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_FULL_PART_IND="P" AND SZVIRST_LEVL_CODE="01", 1, 0)) AS [PartTimeGraduates]
FROM BANINST1_SZVIRST
GROUP BY 
    BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_TERM_DESC, 
    BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_TERM_CODE, 
    BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_LEVL_CODE, 
    BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_FULL_PART_IND
WHERE BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_TERM_CODE IN ("201020","201120","201220","201320","201420","201520","201620")
```

Comment: But still its showing me ERROR: syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_FULL_PART_IND
WHERE [BANINST1_SZVIRST.SZVIRST_TERM_CODE] IN ("201020","201120","201220","201320","201420","201520","201620")'

Comment: I'm not Access expert, but I believe you need to put brackets around your tables and fields, not both at the same time. So `[BANINST1_SZVIRST].[SZVIRST_TERM_CODE]`